# Start load wkwebview after about 10 seconds white page

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, wkwebview

I want load a remote url page, but it always start to load after about 10 seconds
the code is below

```
- (UIWebView *)webView {
    if(!_webView) {
        _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)];
        _webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        _webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
        _webView.delegate = self;
    }
   return _webView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   [self editNavigationBar];
   NSLog(@"viewLodLoad");
   self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   [self loadHTML:self.pageModel.url title:self.pageModel.postUser];
   [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
}
-(void)editNavigationBar {
    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];
    NSLog(@"start Load WebView"); 
    [self loadWebView];
}


//load URL
 - (void)loadHTML:(NSString *)htmlString title:(NSString *)title
 {
    self.request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:htmlString]];
   self.title = title;
   [self.webView loadRequest:self.request];
}
```

but the log result is ....

```
2017-01-22 10:04:48.867 xxx[5404:1574257] start Load WebView

2017-01-22 10:04:48.868 xxx[5404:1584402] myQueue

2017-01-22 10:04:48.868 xxx[5404:1574257] viewLodLoad

2017-01-22 10:04:48.946 xxx[5404:1574257] mainQueue

2017-01-22 10:05:01.547 xxx[5404:1574257] decidePolicyForNavigationAction    

2017-01-22 10:05:01.548 xxx[5404:1574257] didStartProvisionalNavigation

2017-01-22 10:05:02.468 xxx[5404:1574257] decidePolicyForNavigationResponse
```

Comment: what is like about your url's link? If is more data, you can add a progress bar, because the WKWebView has a callback progress value.

Comment: 6k page.... and the problem is it started to load after very long time

Comment: @SpebcerZ, do you use the lazy init of the  `webView`?

Comment: no, do I need to add a lazy init? I will try right now.

Comment: where you create the `self.webView`? use storyboard? or what?

Comment: @aircraft should I add load request in lazy init?

Comment: @aircraft I write code to initiate a view

Comment: post all your code in the question, let us examine your code.

Comment: @aircraft I have edit code

Comment: I saw, why you need this line? `_webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;` , annotation it to have a try?

Comment: have you tried ? SpencerZ

Comment: @aircraft YES, I have tried, but it is still ....

Comment: if its convenience, send your code to my e-mail: liaodalin19903@126.com I think the problem is not in the post code here.

Comment: has this thing even been resolved? I have exactly the same issue, and my code is virtually the same as the one above (except it is in Swift 3.1).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have all of the GCD stuff in there? It doesn't seem needed. You should be able to reduce it down to:

```
- (void)loadWebView {
    [self loadHTML:self.pageModel.url title:self.pageModel.postUser];
}
```

and I bet that will remove your 10s delay.

Comment: at first , I wrote like this, but it was still......so I add it to a thread